# How to constrain camera and prevent roll behaviour with PCLVisualizer

Tags: point-cloud-library

I'm building an app with QT, VTK and PCL. I'm using the `QVTKWidget` and `PCLVisualizer`. I believe the standard interactor style is a `PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle` which behaves like a `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera`.

The default behaviour is very unconstrained and with the mouse it's easy to get rolled on the side, upside down or under the (imaginary) floor. I think the biggest gain would be to disable the roll behaviour and constrain the azimuth angle, for my use case at least.

Does anyone have experience with tweaking the camera behaviour like this or any idea how it might be done?